# grep patterns from file1 into column of file2

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have two files:

```
$ cat File1
A
B
C
```

```
$ cat File2
A aaa B
D bbb A
B aaa h
```

I would like to search patterns from `File1` into `File2`, a sort of what `grep -f File1 File2` would do, but searching the patterns reported in `File1` only in `$1` of `File2`

Sample output:

```
$cat File3
A aaa B
B aaa h
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have a modified version of File1: `sed 's/^/^/' File1 > File1-anchored`? Then use that modified file as pattern file for `grep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=NR; next} a[$1]' f1.txt f2.txt
```

- `NR==FNR{a[$0]=NR; next}`: for first file (`f1.txt`) we are putting the record as key to an assiciative array with the corresponding record number as the value
- `a[$1]`: for second file (`f2.txt`), the record is only printed if the first field is a key of array `a`

**Example:**

```
% cat f1.txt                                       
A
B
C

% cat f2.txt                                       
A aaa B
D bbb A
B aaa h

% awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=NR; next} a[$1]' f1.txt f2.txt
A aaa B
B aaa h
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` command:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

If the files are sorted.

```
join file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` or any shell that understands process substitution:

```
$ grep -f <( awk '{ printf("^%s[[:blank:]]\n", $0) }' File1 ) File2
A aaa B
B aaa h
```

The idea here is to create the correct patterns for `grep -f File1` to work directly on `File2` by transforming each line in `File` from `something` to the regular expression `^something[[:blank:]]` (prefix it with a circumflex and suffix it with `[[:blank:]]`).

The circumflex anchors the pattern to the start of the line and `[[:blank:]]` forces a match against a space or a tab character.

GNU `grep` may also read patterns from standard input:

```
$ awk '{ printf("^%s[[:blank:]]\n", $0) }' File1 | grep -f - File2
A aaa B
B aaa h
```

The `awk` command may be replaced by an equivalent `sed` command (if you prefer `sed` over `awk`):

```
$ sed -e 's/^/^/' -e 's/$/[[:blank:]]/' File1 | grep -f - File2
```